# Deploying Codeigniter App on Amazon AWS

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently enrolled to basic version of Amazon AWS. I was able to create a new instance and get it running state in the console. Can anyone please guide how to upload a sample php file and redirect to GoDaddy domain.

Read a lot of their online help but couldn't figure out the procedure.

Comment: If you found out the procedure, can you please help me? Looking for the same

Answer (score -3):

Please follow the following steps. This is for Ubuntu 14.04

1. Setup an Web server with database and PHP
   Refer: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04
2. Install PhpMyAdmin for setting up database
   Refer: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04
3. Upload your database through PhpMyAdmin dashboard.
4. Connect to sever using SFTP clients like FileZilla or WinSCP.
5. Goto your webroot directory (By default /var/www/html) and upload the code.
6. Change the database username, password & database name in the database configuration file of your app code.
7. Login to Godaddy domain section and create an A record for the domain and set value as the public ip of your AWS Instance.
8. It will take some time to reflect in DNS. Meanwhile you can test the working of application by going to the public ip of AWS Instance.